# Custom loss function with regularization cost added in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

I wrote a custom loss function that add the regularization loss to the total loss, I added L2 regularizer to kernels only, but when I called model.fit() a warning appeared which states that the gradients does not exist for those biases, and biases are not updated, also if I remove a regularizer from a kernel of one of the layers, the gradient for that kernel also does not exist.

I tried to add bias regularizer to each layer and everything worked correctly, but I don't want to regularize the biases, so what should I do?

Here is my loss function:

```
 def _loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    # convert tensors to numpy arrays
    y_true_n = y_true.numpy()
    y_pred_n = y_pred.numpy()
    # modify probablities for Knowledge Distillation loss
    # we do this for old tasks only
    old_y_true = np.float_power(y_true_n[:, :-1], 0.5)
    old_y_true = old_y_true / np.sum(old_y_true)
    old_y_pred = np.float_power(y_pred_n[:, :-1], 0.5)
    old_y_pred = old_y_pred / np.sum(old_y_pred)
    # Define the loss that we will used for new and old tasks
    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
    # compute the loss on old tasks
    old_loss = bce(old_y_true, old_y_pred)
    # compute the loss on new task
    new_loss = bce(y_true_n[:, -1], y_pred_n[:, -1])
    # compute the regularization loss
    reg_loss = tf.compat.v1.losses.get_regularization_loss()
    assert reg_loss is not None
    # convert all tensors to float64
    old_loss = tf.cast(old_loss, dtype=tf.float64)
    new_loss = tf.cast(new_loss, dtype=tf.float64)
    reg_loss = tf.cast(reg_loss, dtype=tf.float64)
    return old_loss + new_loss + reg_loss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keras, loss function should return the loss value **without** regularization losses. The regularization losses will be added automatically by setting kernel_regularizer or bias_regularizer in each of the keras layers.

In other words, when you write your custom loss function, you don't have to care about regularization losses.

**Edit:** the reason why you got the warning messages that gradients don't exist is because of the usage of `numpy()` in your loss function. `numpy()` will stop any gradient propagation.

The warning messages disappeared after you added regularizers to the layers **do not** imply that the gradients were then computed correctly. It would only include the gradients from the regularizers but not from the data. `numpy()` should be removed in the loss function in order to get the correct gradients.

One of the solutions is to keep everything in tensors and use tf.math library. e.g. use `tf.pow` to replace `np.float_power` and `tf.reduce_sum` to replace `np.sum`

Comment: I do as you said, but the same warnings still appear

Comment: Can you provide a reference for your Answer?

Comment: Oh, I missed that there is a mistake in your loss function of calling numpy(). You cannot call numpy() which will stop gradients. I am going to add to my answer.

Comment: Regarding to the reference that "loss function should return the loss value without regularization losses", I don't think that tensorflow has documented that very clearly, that's why I am answering. I know that from reading the source code of tensorflow and observing the behavior of the loss values by looking at the logging of model.fit.

Comment: If you want to verify, you can have an experiment like this, passing tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(name='total_loss') and tf.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy(name='bce') (please notice that one is metrics and another one is loss) to model.compile() and also adding regularization to your model. Then, in the logging of model.fit(), you will figure out that total loss is greater than bce.

Comment: I set run_eagerly=True when compiling the model, this allows me to convert to numpy arrays, I will try to remove that and use tensorflow.math library instead, but
since kernels are updated correctly why biases are not?

Comment: Everything works fine after using tensorflow.math library instead of dealing with numpy arrays and removing the run_eagerly=True, but can you please explain why this happened?

Comment: I edited the answer. Please see if it helps.